# Angular Route NESTED NG-VIEW / NG-TEMPLATE

Tags: angularjs

i am just starting with angular and i have a problem,

I am using ng-view with route to make an SPA,
then i have my controler

```
App.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/Home', {
            templateUrl: '/Templates/Home.html',
            controller: 'HomeController'
        }).(...) otherwise({
             templateUrl: '/Templates/Home.html',
             controller: 'HomeController'
         });
});
```

Everything was ok and the SPA worked like a charm, until i created a new template

/template/XPTO.html
that contained an NG repeater with multiple includes:

```
<div class="content" ng-switch on="control.CONTROL_TYPE">
    <div ng-switch-when="MAIN_PANEL_TITLE">
        <div ng-include="'/HomeControls/Title.html'" ng-controller="HomeControlsController"
             onload="InstanceId = control.ID; LoadTitle(InstanceId)">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="FULL_PANEL_NEWS">
        <div ng-include="'/HomeControls/FullPageNews.html'" ng-controller="HomeControlsController"
             onload="InstanceId = control.ID; LoadFullNews(InstanceId)">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

After this any time i go to the XPTO page the browser breaks, but works ok with all other pages... any ideia what it migth be? i assume its a problem with route against nested ng-view / ng-template

Thanks

Comment: what does "the browser breaks" mean?

Answer (score 0):

view / ui router solved the problem
thanks every one